# How to save and delete data automatically in Django database?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a website using Django, but I would like to update my database for every 15 mins with new scraped data. Also, I would like to delete the old data that has been saved for longer than  one week.

I was able to do it manually by using Django `manage.py shell`, but how can I make it automatically?

Is there any library for automatic database management that is compatible with Django?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a fairly complex task to accomplish, you may wanna look into (assuming you're using scrapy) scrapy pipelines https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html. And to delete the task after `n` days you can either try out Django Celery https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html, or Django background tasks https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: You could also make a django management command and a cron job that runs it every 15 mins. Or django-rq is  a good alternative: https://github.com/rq/django-rq

Comment: Thank you for all the comments! It seems that it is somehow feasible. I will try to search those things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just implemented something similar myself, I'd have to agree with the comments in saying that this is a relatively involved process. Nevertheless, it is quite doable, and there is a ton of info out there on the particulars. I'll give you an overview of what I did.

My goal was to automatically run a function in my Django app every weekday at 16:00.

A quick search will tell you that you want to set up a periodic task schedule. For that I needed:

- [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) - A popular task queue/scheduling system with Django compatibility
- [Redis](https://redis.io/) - The broker I opted to use
- [Django Celery Beat](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat) - Celery Beat is the periodic task scheduling part of Celery - this Django package adds database integrations so that you can control the schedule of your events from the admin panel

A setup using these 3 elements will provide everything you need to set up what you're looking for. In terms of implementation, I could try and type it all out here, but I feel I would just be copying the guides I followed. I found [this one](https://www.revsys.com/tidbits/celery-and-django-and-docker-oh-my/) particularly useful, but I assume you're not using Docker (I recommend you do though!). Either way, between that and the official Celery [Getting Started Guide](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps) and Django Celery Beat [guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes), you'll have everything you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, JB. I will try to figure out the three elements. It is my first time to deal with back-end part, so I am getting a lot of help here. Thank you again!